# Subdomain Apache2 Different Methods nothing working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, subdomain

I have got an website example.com

I want to have subdomain **blog.example.com** (which content is located in /var/www/blog).

I generated new IP for subdomain on my server. The main domain is on xxxx01 and the subdomain is on xxxx02. Evertyhing is made in domain provider.

So I made a file here **apache2/sites-available/blog**:

```
<VirtualHost xxxx02:80>
        ServerName blog.example.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www/blog
        <Directory /var/www/blog>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/red-error.log

        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/red-access.log combined

    </VirtualHost>
```

I enabled subdomain with **a2ensite**.

**etc/hosts**:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
xxxx02 blog.example.com
```

What I have to do? Help me guys please!

Comment: Is your apache listening on `xxxx02:80` ?

Comment: Probably not, 'cause I not made any more changes. Where and how to add it if possible or any another method?

Comment: Depends on your configuration, you should find some `Listen ...` lines in your apache configs (for example in httpd.conf, ports.conf - really depends). Furthermore: Did you restart apache after setting up the 2nd interface? What's the error you get? Connection Refused?

Comment: I've got in my ports.conf something like this:

NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80

Yes, I made an reset. The error is: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: Did you check (on your client) that `xxx02` is actually resolving to your ip address?

Comment: Yes, it's not working. I changed the DNS A to blog.example.com and A too to example.com and changed hosts to blog.example.com on the main IP.
It will be working? In /blog conf i changed to *80